# Custom monotonic loss function multi-output R keras

Tags: r, keras, loss-function

For multi-output regression networks we usually know something about the relationship between the outputs. For my example, I know that the outputs are monotonically increasing for each observation,

```
# number of observations
N <- 1000

# synthetic multiple outputs
y1 <- rnorm(N,20,5) # smallest
y2 <- y1 + rnorm(N,7,2) # middle
y3 <- y2 + rnorm(N,7,2) # largest
Y <- data.frame(y1,y2,y3) # combine
Y <- Y * rexp(N,2) # randomly scale rows
```

The rows of Y monotonically increase as you move from left to right (y1-y3). The relationship *between rows* is not important. A good model will learn that for each observation it should produce predictions that increase from y1 to y3 as this is always true in the training data. For this simple example and enough epochs the network learns this just fine. In my real-world example, however, there are 3000 observations, 35 covariates, and 27 outputs. The model for the real dataset does not always produce monotonic outputs. To demonstrate the idea intentionally underfit this model to violate monotonicity in the predictions.

Create predictor variables and training and test sets,

```
# synthetic nonlinear predictors
x1 <- (sqrt(y1) + rnorm(N,0,1))^2
x2 <- log10((x1 + y2)^3)
x3 <- sqrt(abs(y3-y2))
x4 <- sqrt((x1 + y2)^2)

X <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4) %>% # combine
  mutate_all(funs(scale)) %>% # scale
  as.matrix() # to matrix

# create train and test set
set.seed(0)
ind <- sample(2, N, replace=T, prob=c(0.50, 0.50))

Xtrain <- X[ind==1,]
Ytrain <- Y[ind==1,]
Xtest <- X[ind==2,]
Ytest <- Y[ind==2,]
```

Build keras model and intentionally underfit,

```
library(keras)
library(tidyverse)

# add covariates
input <- layer_input(shape=dim(X)[2],name="covars")

# add hidden layers
base_model <- input  %>%
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation='relu') 

# add output 1 
yhat1 <- base_model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, name="yhat1") 

# add output 2
yhat2 <- base_model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, name="yhat2") 

# add output 3
yhat3 <- base_model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, name="yhat3")

# caclulate squared weights for mse loss
weight_fun <- function(x){mean(Y$y1/x)}
weights <- as.numeric(apply(Y,2,weight_fun))^2

# build multi-output model
model <- keras_model(input,list(yhat1,yhat2,yhat3)) %>%
  compile(optimizer = "rmsprop",
          loss="mse",
          metrics="mae",
          loss_weights=weights)

# fit model (intentionally underfit)
model_fit <- model %>% 
  fit(x=Xtrain,
      y=list(Ytrain[,1],Ytrain[,2],Ytrain[,3]), 
      epochs=75, 
      batch_size = 25, 
      validation_split = 0.1, 
      verbose=0)
```

Predict on test set and count the number of violations,

```
# predict values for test set
Yhat <- predict(model, Xtest) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(colnames(Y))

# sum monotonic violations 
sum(apply(Yhat,1,function(x){sum(cummax(x)!=x)}))
sum(apply(Ytest,1,function(x){sum(cummax(x)!=x)}))
```

There will be some number of violations for Yhat and 0 for Ytest. I am interested in adding a constraint to the output via a modified loss function. If *k* is the number of outputs, *i* is the number of observations, and omega (w) is a weight matrix for each outputs loss, then the multi-ouput loss is the weighted average of the individual MSEs for each output,

[image]

And a way to write the monotonic loss might be,

[image]

Where for each observation we are simply summing the number of times monotonicity is violated. Finally, we could combine them like this,

[image]

Where alpha is a scalar to force the MSE and monotonic error term to be on the same scale. The loss function (without the alpha weights for now) will look something like this,

```
# custom loss function
loss_custom <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  val <- k_placeholder(dtype = 'float32')
  mse <- k_placeholder(dtype = 'float32')
  n <- k_placeholder(dtype = 'float32')
  k <- k_placeholder(dtype = 'float32')
  n <- k_shape(y_pred)[[1]]
  k <- k_shape(y_pred)[[2]]
  y_pred <- array_reshape(y_pred,dim=c(k,n))
  y_true <- array_reshape(y_true,dim=c(k,n))
  val <- k_sum(k_cast(k_less(y_pred[2:k]-y_pred[1:k-1],0),'float32'))
  mse <- k_mean(k_square(y_true-y_pred)) 
  return(mse + val)
}
```

but this results in several errors, the main source of which is me not understanding how the predictions for each output are returned in y_pred. My main questions are (1) how to I access the three predictions while training (2) to add the monotonicity constraint?